How to fix NJS-505: unable to initiate TLS connection. Please check if wallet credentials are valid in node-oracledb
I have created an oracle wallet using orapki and imported truststore certificates into it. I have an RDS oracle database in AWS and when trying to connect to it using the oracle wallet I get this error:
[2024-11-07T13:31:04.692] [ERROR] oracleDBWrapper - Error: NJS-505: unable to initiate TLS connection. Please check if wallet credentials are valid
    at Object.throwErr (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/errors.js:603:10)
    at NTTCP.connect (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/sqlnet/ntTcp.js:237:18)
    at async NetworkSession.transportConnect (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/sqlnet/networkSession.js:173:5)
    at async NetworkSession.connect2 (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/sqlnet/networkSession.js:211:7)
    at async NetworkSession.connect1 (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/sqlnet/networkSession.js:314:23)
    at async NetworkSession.connect (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/sqlnet/networkSession.js:530:5)
    at async ThinConnectionImpl.connect (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/connection.js:628:5)
    at async ThinPoolImpl.bgThreadFunc (/home/node/node_modules/oracledb/lib/thin/pool.js:420:11) {
  code: 'NJS-505'
}

However using this same wallet and sqlplus I can connect fine so it seems the wallet is fine. On my local machine I added in some logging to ntTcp.js and checked the exact error is:
Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
    at setKey (node:internal/tls/secure-context:92:11)
    at configSecureContext (node:internal/tls/secure-context:174:7)
    at Object.createSecureContext (node:_tls_common:121:3)
    at NTTCP.connect 


Try Thick mode node-oracledb.

Using thick mode does fix the issue however I would prefer to be able to use thin mode as using thick mode means I need to include the oracle binaries with my node application and I am trying to avoid that if possible

Can you try adding the wallet by setting NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS.
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1593

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Adding this variable does not fix the issue
